# R - Concatenate SQL query string over multiple lines

Tags: sql, r, string

I have a SQL query like this (example set, the query is actually much long and has multiple lines):

```
 Select entity, date, value 
 from Test.DB.View1
 where entity='abc'
```

I have a `string` ; `entityvalue = 'abc'` which is dynamic; changes based on user selection.

I would like to build a SQL query string that could incorporate entityvalue. For example:

```
paste("Select entity, date, value 
     from Test.DB.View1
     where entity='",entityvalue,"'",sep= " ")
```

The result from the above syntax becomes:

```
"Select entity, date, value \n         from Test.DB.View1\n         where entity='abc'"
```

What's the best way to avoid `\n` ?

Comment: Why is `\n` a problem? I've not found a SQL server that complains.

Comment: Side note: pasting _data_ into a _query_ is a bad practice to get into, for several reasons. I strongly recommend reading https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/ and using anything other than `entity='abc'` (regardless of the presence of `\n`), namely bound-parameters or `glue_sql` (I'm fond of the former).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the chunks to `paste()`

```
paste("Select entity, date, value",
     "from Test.DB.View1",
     "where entity='", entityvalue ,"'",sep= " ")
```